# iOS SKProductsRequest returns products as invalid identifiers

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, skproduct

I'm testing my iOS app In-App Purchase module and SKProductsRequest started returning inconsistent results.

On one request it returns my product in "invalidProductIdentifiers" property and after a few requests it returns it as valid in "products" property. I don't see a consistent pattern in this.

I've read TN2259(https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2259/_index.html) and all the steps are fulfilled, or they seem to be.
My product is a consumable "Ready to Submit", attached to an app version that is in "Prepare for Submission".

I've tested with a different bundle identifier, code signing and provisioning profile from an app where this behaviour dosen't apper, which leeds me to think that there is something in the way my app is configured in iTunes Connect or signed.

Ideas why SKProductsRequest returns my product as invalid sometimes and valid other times?